# Angular sortable list and ngFor last element reference

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm learning Angular 6 and decided to use [jQuerUI sortable plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) to handle the drag/drop/sort functionality in Todo application. Plugin works as expected. I can move items around between lists, but I've noticed some weird behavior. When I move the last item from list **1** to list **2** and then click the "+Add Task" button on list **1**, fill the title and save, it renders in list **2** instead of list **1** as expected.

Is `*ngFor` holding a reference to the last rendered element and then just adds next element right after? Is there a way to prevent such behavior?

[image: GOOD and BAD behavior]

**list.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <div class="lists-container">
    <div class="list mx-4" *ngFor="let list of todosLists">
      <i class="fas fa-times cross cross-red" (click)="deleteList(list)"></i>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <p class="list-title">{{list.title}}</p>
      </div>
      <ul appDragnDropDirective [parentList]="list" (updated)="dragging($event)" class="col-sm list-size drag-drop empty-list-height">
        <li (click)="edit(todo)" *ngFor="let todo of list.todos"
            class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 card-size">
          <div class="card-header">{{todo?.title}}</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">{{todo?.description}}</p>
            <p class="card-text"> listId={{todo?.listId}}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <div *ngIf="newTaskFormHidden.checked" class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 card-size card-form">
          <div class="card-header">
            <input class="w-100 form-control" type="text" placeholder="Task title"
                   (input)="''" #title>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <button (click)="addTodo(title.value, list.id); title.value = ''" type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                    [disabled]="!title.value">Save
            </button>
            <button (click)="newTaskFormHidden.checked = !newTaskFormHidden.checked"
                    type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <input hidden type="checkbox" #newTaskFormHidden>
      <div *ngIf="!newTaskFormHidden.checked">
        <button
          class="btn btn-add-gray btn-block"
          type="button"
          (click)="newTaskFormHidden.checked = !newTaskFormHidden.checked">+ Add task
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm list-size">
      <input hidden type="checkbox" #newListFormHidden>
      <div *ngIf="newListFormHidden.checked" class="col-sm list">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <input (keyup.enter)="addList(listTitle.value); listTitle.value = ''"
                 class="w-100 form-control mb-2" type="text" placeholder="List title" (input)="''" #listTitle>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                  [disabled]="!listTitle.value" (click)="addList(listTitle.value); listTitle.value = ''">Save
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"
                  (click)="newListFormHidden.checked = !newListFormHidden.checked">Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button *ngIf="!newListFormHidden.checked" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block mt-3"
              (click)="newListFormHidden.checked = !newListFormHidden.checked">+ Add list
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**list.component.ts(just add function)**

```js
addTodo(title: string, listId: number): void {
    this.loggerService.add(`Add todo: title: ${title}, listId: ${listId}`);
    this.todoService.addTodo({title, listId} as Todo).subscribe(
      todo => {
        const list = this.todosLists.find(l => l.id === todo.listId);
        list.todos.push(todo);
      }
    );
  }
```

**dragndrop.directive.ts**

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

declare let $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDragnDropDirective]'
})
export class DragndropDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() cssClassToConnect;
  @Input() parentList;
  @Output() updated = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setupDragAndDrop();
  }

  private setupDragAndDrop() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).sortable({
      connectWith: this.cssClassToConnect || '.drag-drop',
      placeholder: 'card-placeholder',
      dropOnEmpty: true,
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      items: 'li:not(.card-form)',
      start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.outerHeight());
      },
      stop: (event, ui) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui.item.position());
        this.updated.emit(this.parentList);
      }
    }).disableSelection();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery UI is simply moving the HTML DOM Element from one `<ul>` to another, and this is messing up Angular's `*ngFor` as it is referencing the last element rendered from the list in the DOM.

As your UI clearly displays, the moved "todo" still has the previous `listId`, so I think you need to trigger a change in Angular so that it will re-work the DOM references on a re-render.

I think if you hook into the event when you switch the "todo" over to the other list and actually **splice that todo out of the previous list and append it to the other** then Angular will re-render the DOM and you will get your normal expected behavior.